# How to make an ajax request in login form with spring security?

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I read several articles and followed them but they didn't work in my case.
My login form is as follows:-

```
<div style="text-align: center; padding: 30px; border: 1px solid; width: 300px;">

    <form method="post"
          action='j_spring_security_check' id="login_form" >

      <table>

        <tr>

          <td colspan="2" style="color: red">${message}</td>

        </tr>


        <tr>

          <td>User Name:</td>


          <td><input type="text" name="j_username" id="uname"  value='<c:if test="${not empty param.login_error}">
                                                     <c:out value="${SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME}"/>
                                                     </c:if>' /></td>

        </tr>


        <tr>

          <td>Password:</td>


          <td><input type="password" name="j_password" /></td>

        </tr>


        <tr>

          <td colspan="1"><input type="submit" value="Login" /></td>


          <td colspan="1"><input name="reset" type="reset" /></td>

        </tr>

      </table>

    </form>

  </div>
```

I am making ajax request as follows:-

```
<script>

        $("#login_form").submit(function(e){
            var formUrl = $("#login_form").attr("action");
            var postData=$("#login_form").serializeArray();
            $.ajax({
                url:"/abhishekchat/j_spring_security_check",
                method:POST,
                data:postData,
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {

                    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Ajax-call", "true");

                },

                success:function(response){console.log("success");},
                error:function(response){console.log("operation failed");}

            });
            e.preventDefault();
        });
        $("#login_form").submit();
    </script>
```

But i am unable to make ajax request. I want to ask what should i do in order to make ajax request. My spring-security.xml is as follows:-

```
<beans:beans xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
             xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
             xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd">


    <security:http auto-config="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/search*" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
        <security:form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/search" authentication-failure-url="/login1" />
        <security:logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider >

            <!-- <security:user-service>
                   <security:user name="admin" password="admin123" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
               </security:user-service>-->
            <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
                                        users-by-username-query="select firstName,password,enabled from user100 where firstName=?"
                                        authorities-by-username-query="select u100.firstName,role from user_roles as urole, user100 as u100 where urole.firstName=?"
                    />
            <!--</security:authentication-provider>
        </security:authentication-manager>-->
            <!--<security:authentication-manager>
                <security:authentication-provider>
                    <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"

                                       users-by-username-query="
                          select login as username,password
                          from users100 where login=?"

                                       authorities-by-username-query="ROLE_ADMIN"

                            />-->
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <!--<beans:bean id="myUserDetailsService"
                class="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </beans:bean>-->

    <beans:bean id="dataSource"
                class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/abhi" />
        <beans:property name="username" value="root" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="system" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="mysessionFactory"  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></beans:property>

        <beans:property name="mappingResources">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:value>User.hbm.xml</beans:value>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>

        <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</beans:prop>

                <beans:prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>

            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="template" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="mysessionFactory"></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>


    <!---<jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource"/>-->
</beans:beans>
```

Comment: To make ajax request you should use url mapped to the controller.

Comment: since in spring security csrf protection is enabled by default .you should either try disabling it  or you should pass the csrf token in ajax otherwise you form submission will not work

Comment: i passed csrf token as u said but then too not able to send ajax request..:(